# Clojure function explanation.

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain me the stets of this clojure function

```
(defn to-list [{:keys [key left right] :as tree}]
  (when tree
    `(~@(to-list left) ~key ~@(to-list right))))
```

Comment: What part in specific is it that you don't understand?

Comment: `(~@(to-list left) ~key ~@(to-list right))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `to-list` function expects a [map](http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Maps) that has some of three keys, namely `key`, `left` and `right`. This map can be accessed also by the name `tree`. See [this](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844#maps) for argument destructuring. Then you have a syntax quote (see [this](https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html) for details). It is roughly equivalent to

```
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (to-list left) 
                                       (clojure.core/list key) 
                                       (to-list rirght)))
```

So basically if you have `nil` for tree, it will return `nil` (which seems reasonable). If you have a tree with a key `left` (which is either nil or also a map possibly with keys `key`, `left` and `right`), then left tree is recursively printed, then the key is added, then if you have a key `right`, the right tree is printed recursively. If at any step you have only left or only right, the call `(to-list left)` will yield nil and the rest will work as already explained.

I hope this helps.

**NOTE** I don't have a clojure repl right now, so I did not test what is the exact equivalent of syntax-quote, but it should be very something similar to the thing that I wrote.